# Weird UITableView scrolling problem

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I have a sectioned UITableView which loads data from a plist file. The table uses custom cells with dynamic height to fit the content of each cell. The table loads just fine initially, but after scrolling down and back up, the cells seem to be overlaying one another in some sections.

I've attached an image illustrating the issue I am having.

http://img20.imageshack.us/i/photo1b.png/

Any ideas on where to begin troubleshooting this problem?

Comment: How did you set the height of the cell? Can you show some of that code? My guess is that when cells are reused, they're not getting their height reset correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set height for each cell in

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```